# Sending emails in Sentry onpremise docker installation fails

Tags: docker, sentry

We have an installation of Sentry OnPremise 8.22.0 running in Docker on an ubuntu machine. I have set the config.yml with the SMTP account, I tried an internal account and also my gmail account.

Both times, I restarted the docker container, the settings are reflected in sentry manage/status/mail/, but after I click on the button send a test email, it works for a while and then gives me the error message 
`[Errno -2] Name or service not known`

I tried checking the sentry logs, but the internal project doesn't contain any error, and I can't find sentry logs in docker or ubuntu.

From inside the docker, I tried to ping the hostname, but the docker container doesn't have a ping or curl installed so no luck there.

I think the problem relates to the sentry docker container can't resolve the email domain names, but I can't prove it, since I don't have logs or way to check it.

I would be glad for any advice how to proceed, without removing the docker containers and rebuilding them from scratch ...